# Long HTML source in Textview

Tags: android, textview

My app is able to show short HTML source in textview. However, with long HTML source, it just doesn't work. The HTML shows correctly in web browser.

Example HTML :

```
<font color='#26D4CB' /><u>Title</u></font><br>Text<br><br><font color='#26D4CB' /><u>Title Title Title Title Title Title</u></font><br>some long text some long text some long text some long text <br><br><font color='#26D4CB' /><u>Title Title Title Title Title Title</u></font><br><br><font color='#26D4CB' /><u>Title Title Title Title Title Title</u></font><br>+ rework of the emoji picker<br>some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text
```

I am using both

```
tvChangelog.setText(Html.fromHtml(changelog),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

and

```
tvChangelog.setText(Html.fromHtml(changelog));
```

Yet both doesn't achieve any results. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm..that seems to work for me..what kind of unexpected result do you get ?

Comment: Really? I only got <br> and <u> to work. Yet the color never change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You HTML does not seem correct (especially the `<font>` elements). Try to replace it with the following:

```
<font color='#26D4CB'><u>Title</u></font><br>Text<br><br><font color='#26D4CB'><u>Title Title Title Title Title Title</u></font><br>some long text some long text some long text some long text <br><br><font color='#26D4CB'><u>Title Title Title Title Title Title</u></font><br><br><font color='#26D4CB'><u>Title Title Title Title Title Title</u></font><br>+ rework of the emoji picker<br>some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text</u></font>
```